# Bootstrap carousel buttons appearing wrong

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

For my website the I used the bootstrap carousel for my home page. The carousel works but for some reason it's not displaying the next/prev arrows. I can click where the arrows would be to advance the carousel. The website is [codehighway.org](http://codehighway.org) if anyone would like to inspect the elements. Here's the code for the home page as well. Any help would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Code Highway</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Code for the nav-bar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.html">Code Highway</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Lessons</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="cs1.html">Computer Science 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="cs2.html">Computer Science 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Algorithms and Data Structures</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End of nav-bar -->

<!-- Start of carousel -->

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Slider Content (Wrapper for slides )-->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="test.jpg" alt="quote"  style="float: none;margin:0 auto;display: block;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="test2.jpg" alt="quote"  style="float: none;margin:0 auto;display: block;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="test3.jpg" alt="quote"  style="float: none;margin:0 auto;display: block;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>


<!-- End of carousel -->  



<!-- Code for jumbotron -->

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Start learning code</h1>
  <p>Hello, I'm Maurice this is my personal website. I show programming concepts, my portfolio of projects, and a blog where I give tips tricks or any type of recommendations.</p>
</div>

<!-- End of jumbotron -->

  </body>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm noticing in my developer console that Bootstrap's font files for glyphicons are all 404ing on your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Bootstrap stylesheet is being hosted at http://codehighway.org/bootstrap.min.css. However, this stylesheet is searching for the glyphicon font files at `../fonts/`. This path does not exist, which causes your font files to 404, which causes your icons to break.

You should move `bootstrap.min.css` to a new directory at `/css` and the fonts to a new directory at `/fonts`. This should fix your issues with relative paths and get the icons to work.

An alternate solution is to use a CDN like [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com) to host these files for you (and their version of `bootstrap.min.css` includes links to their hosted glyphicon font files).

Comment: Thanks Nicolas you were right. It was a quick fix, thanks for the help.